# looping in Vue.JS to iterate over some a group of items and wrapping them in an element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I am new in Vue, I want to create a Loop (v-for) for creating something like  this block

```
<div class="The-row">
 <span> {{ * }} </span>
 <span> {{ * }} </span>
</div>
```

in this block each 2 span wrap with a Tag with " The-row " class and each SPAN tag has an instead item , that means :

```
<div class="The-row">
 <span> {{ item[0] }} </span>
 <span> {{ item[1] }} </span>
</div>
----------------------------------
<div class="The-row">
 <span> {{ item[2] }} </span>
 <span> {{ item[3] }} </span>
</div>
```

what am i doing for create loop , i know this way for show an element in every twice loop with use

```
<div v-if=" index % 2 == 0 " >
```

see this pen -> https://codepen.io/hamidrezanikoonia/pen/RQrvKJ

in this pen , i have 2 important proble
  1. the first item dosent show
  2. the items cant be even

and , please check im in correct way or i can use another way

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also would prefer changing the structure of the data rather then building a complicated template. But it would work like this:

```
<div class="option-row" v-if="($index + 1) % 2 == 1 ">

  <input class="option-input" id="option-1" type="radio" name="options" />
  <label class="option" for="option-1">
    <span class="option__label">
      <sub>{{item.name}}</sub>
    </span>
  </label>

  <input v-if="items[$index + 1]" class="option-input" id="option-1" type="radio" name="options" />
  <label v-if="items[$index + 1]" class="option" for="option-1">
    <span class="option__label">
      <sub>{{items[($index + 1)].name}}</sub>
    </span>
  </label>

</div>
```

This is the same solution Richard Matsen already mentioned. Only with a little enhancement: avoid errors if the odd element doesn't exist.

You can use a computed property for this:

```
computed: {
    groupedItems() {
        let grouped = [];
        index = -1;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) { 
                index++;
                grouped[index] = [];
            }
            grouped[index].push(this.items[i]);
        }
        return grouped;
    }
}
```

And your Template would get cleaner:

```
<template v-for="items in groupedItems">
    <div class="option-row">
        <div v-for="item in items">
            <input class="option-input" id="option-1" type="radio" name="options" />
            <label class="option" for="option-1">
                <span class="option__label">
                    <sub>{{item.name}}</sub>
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>  
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: i changed my pen now [link](https://codepen.io/hamidrezanikoonia/pen/WMwRVE?editors=1010) and i have new question , can u gime me more information about create computed property and what benefits of  use groupedItems ?  thanks bro

Comment: the benefit of a computed property is in this case, that you don't have to change your initial data structure. the computed property do the job for grouping the data for the template.

Answer (score 1):

you can working in this way

```
computed: {
groupedItems() {
    let grouped = [];
    index = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) { 
            index++;
            grouped[index] = [];
        }
        grouped[index].push(this.items[i]);
    }
    return grouped;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try grouping the data (using a computed property), rather than make the template more complicated.

However, the shortest fix is to swap your indexes, since `$index === 0` is hidden and `$index === 1` is shown, etc.

```html
<input class="option-input"...
<label class="option" for="option-1">
  <span class="option__label">
    <sub>{{items[$index -1].name}}</sub> 
  </span>
</label>

<input class="option-input"...
<label class="option" for="option-1">
  <span class="option__label">
    <sub>{{items[$index].name}}</sub> 
  </span>
</label>
```

---

Here is a shorter version of the grouping function.

Ref: [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
console.clear()
const items = [
  { id: 1 , name: 'one'},
  { id: 2 , name: 'two'},
  { id: 3 , name: 'three'},
  { id: 4 , name: 'four'},
  { id: 5 , name: 'five'},
  { id: 6 , name: 'six'},
  { id: 7 , name: 'seven'},
  { id: 8 , name: 'eight'},
  { id: 9 , name: 'nine'},
  { id: 10 , name: 'ten'}
];

const grouped = items.reduce((acc, item, index, items) => {
  return index % 2 === 0 ? acc : [...acc, [items[index -1], item]];
}, [])

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: thanks Richard for answer my question , and what different between , use ` items.[$index -1]` and ' items.[$index + 1]' ?

Comment: Well, as I mentioned index 0 is skipped - so you have to look backward not forward.